# How to use case in date field

Tags: mysql, sql

I Want to calling_number in one field and month wise records with calling number

```
SELECT calling_number, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN Date(start_time) BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-31' THEN 
           Sec_to_time(Sum(duration)) 
           ELSE NULL 
         end ) AS March, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN Date(start_time) BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-31' THEN 
           Sec_to_time(Sum(duration)) 
           ELSE NULL 
         end ) AS April, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN Date (start_time) BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31' THEN 
           Sec_to_time(Sum(duration)) 
           ELSE NULL 
         end ) AS May 
FROM   telephone_report 
GROUP  BY calling_number 
ORDER  BY duration
```

I want to result like this

```
Calling_number    April       May        June
1024              10:20:20    05:10:05   05:00:02
```

Comment: Please, add some sample data and from this sample what would be the desired result. Your question as of now is unclear.

Comment: please show table structure

Comment: By rolling back the previous edit you have made the question unclear. As suggested above please show your code as code blocks by indenting for spaces, to make the question clearer

Comment: I want to: Calling_Number      April        May        June .  Records in same column

Comment: Aside: there is no point to the `ORDER  BY duration` clause, as that would apply to the *result*, not the input, and `duration` is what you are aggregating

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a conditional sum of duration

```
SELECT calling_number, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE  WHEN DATE(start_time) BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-31' THEN duration ELSE 0 END )) March,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE  WHEN DATE(start_time) BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-30' THEN duration ELSE 0 END )) April,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE  WHEN DATE(start_time) BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31' THEN duration ELSE 0 END )) May
FROM   telephone_report 
GROUP  BY calling_number
```

Comment: I found this 07:57:50.000000 but want to 07:57:50

Comment: @T.r. can you include sample data for your table `telephone_report` in your question ?

Comment: 1024              10:20:20    05:10:05   05:00:02. I want to hour:minutes and sec only

Comment: You have `Time` values. It is better that the DB has nothing to do with how those are *formatted* for display